# i wana delete a text automatically after few seconds of inactivity

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
import tkinter as tk


class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.config(padx=100, pady=50)
        self.root.geometry('800x600')
        self.text = tk.Text()
        self.entry = tk.Entry()
        self.text.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.text.after(5000, self.clear_text)    # 5000ms
        self.root.mainloop()

    def clear_text(self):
        print ("Le text vient d'etre détruit")
        self.text.place_forget()


app = App()
```

Hello to all,
I am trying to create an Tkinter app where i put some text in a box and if i stop typing for few seconds the text should disappear. I am a beginner, i am stuck!! Thank for giving me an idea!!Yours

Comment: Do you want the text to disappear or do you want the text box to disappear? Also you know that you are creating an `tk.Entry` object that you aren't using. Also also you should pass in `self.root` as the first parameter when creating your `tk.Text` and your `tk.Entry`.

Comment: @TheLizzard _"you should pass in `self.root`..."_ seems incorrect, it is rather recommended, there is no problem even if you do not pass that in.

Comment: @CoolCloud Well given that OP said that they are a *beginer*, and it is part of best practises, I thought that it would be better if OP added the `self.root`. Also if OP doesn't know about that there is no way they can use `Frame`s

Comment: @TheLizzard Yes that is true, but it's still not a _"should"_.

Comment: @CoolCloud Right now I can't change my comment and I used *should* instead of must, to make sure there aren't misunderstandings. Next time I will try to be more clear :D

Comment: I would like the that the text disappear:)

Answer (score 1):

Use `after` and bind `Key` event to the same method. Use an if statement to check if the event parameter of the method is `None`, if it is `None` delete the text.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.config(padx=100, pady=50)
        self.root.geometry('800x600')

        self.delay = 5000
        self.after_id = None

        self.text = tk.Text(self.root)

        self.text.bind("<Key>", self.clear_text)
        self.text.place(x=0, y=0)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def clear_text(self, event=None):
        if not event:
            self.text.delete("1.0", "end")

        else:
            if self.after_id:
                self.root.after_cancel(self.after_id)
                self.after_id = None

            self.after_id = self.root.after(self.delay, self.clear_text)
         
app = App()
```

Comment: There is no point to have `self.after_id = None` inside the `clear_text` method as it will be reset when the code reaches: `self.after_id = ...`. Otherwise a great answer

Comment: Yes, you are correct I must have forgotten to remove it. I was using it when I was trying a different way of getting the program done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from time import perf_counter


class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.text = tk.Text(self.root)
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.bind("<Key>", self.text_entered)

        self.text.after(100, self.check_clear_text)
        self.time_last_written = perf_counter()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def text_entered(self, event):
        self.time_last_written = perf_counter()

    def clear_text(self):
        print("Le text vient d'etre détruit")
        # Delete all of the text
        self.text.delete("0.0", "end")

    def check_clear_text(self):
        time_diff = perf_counter() - self.time_last_written
        print(f"Last key pressed: {time_diff} sec ago.")
        if time_diff > 5: # The 5 is in seconds
            self.clear_text()
        self.text.after(100, self.check_clear_text)


app = App()
```

It keeps track of the last time you pressed a key and if 5 seconds have passed, it deletes all of the widget's contents using: `self.text.delete("0.0", "end")`

Comment: Thank you very much to all for taken time for answering. It helped me a lot. Have a nice day to all!!!